# determining English sentence structure and appropriate response

Tags: java

I'm writing something similar to `smarterChild` (that automated AOL Instant Messenger chat program from back in the day) and was curious about my method of determining sentence structure and response.

Currently, the bare bones design is to use 5 main methods which collectively determine the appropriate response given the user input:

```
    1) Read(): initially accepts user input, then calls first of many methods: sentenceType()
    2) getSentenceType(): User sentence type: Question, statement, directive, suggestion, etc…
    3) getWho(): If question is about the computer, or about someone else…
    4) getCategory(): What category the question is about (weather, sports…)
    5) getResponse(): finally, form a response
```

These methods will query a database to determine if the user input contains key words...

Example of `getSentenceType()`:

```
public String getSentenceType(String sentence) {
    String type = null;

    for (String s : db.getQuestions()) {
        if (sentence.contains(s)) {
            type = "question";
            break;
        }
        else {
            type = "statement";
        }
    }
    return getWho(type, sentence);
}
```

Example of the final method which returns sentence structure:

```
//final call... 
public String getResponse(String cat, String who, String type) {
    String response = new String();     
    String auxVerb, subject, mainVerb, noun; 

    auxVerb = "do";
    subject = who;
    mainVerb = "like";
    noun = cat;

    //question structure: auxiliary verb + subject + main verb + noun/pronoun
    //                      DO              YOU         LIKE        MARY?

    if (type.equals("question")) {
        response = subject + " " + auxVerb + " " + mainVerb + " " + noun +  ". "; 
    }
    else {
        response = auxVerb + " " + subject + " " + mainVerb + " " + noun  + "?";
    }

    return response;
}
```

Sample database methods:

```
public String[] getQuestions() {
    String[] questions = new String[] {"why", "?"}; 
    return questions;
}

public String[] getWeather() {
    String[] weather = new String[] {"cold", "hot", "rainy", "weather"};    
    return weather;
}
```

It will then progressively concatenate all the method results into a coherent response… then send that result back to Read(), which will print out the result to the user...

Is this an inefficient way to go about this? I know that if I continue down this path... to make a robust system, it will take tons of `if else` checks and a massive database to determine every possible type of response for user input.

Are there any suggested methods?

Thank you

Comment: Use an existing NLP library?

Comment: You can avoid reinventing the wheel by starting with a good textbook. The standard one is [Jurafsky and Martin](http://www.amazon.com/Speech-Language-Processing-2nd-Edition/dp/0131873210) but if you dig through the Amazon reviews you should be able to find a better one that is more relevant to your project.

Comment: Noam Chomsky is apparently still alive -- maybe you should ask him.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks Dave. Is the one by Stanford (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml) good for Chinese?

Comment: It *says* it is right on the page you link to, but I don't know Arabic, and have never tried to analyze Chinese.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but maybe an Eliza-style AI would be easier to implement.